# Video.js multiple stream HLS does not work on mobile devices

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js, rtmp, transcoding

I'm streaming at 1080p from OBS to an RTMP server running nginx-http-flv-module and pushed out as multi-stream HLS (using ffmpeg to transcode for lower bitrate/resolution).

```
rtmp {
  server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4096;

    application in {
      live on;
      exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/in/$name -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_1080;
      exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/in/$name -c:v libx264 -b:v 480K -c:a copy -s 854x480 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_480;
    }

    application hls {
      live on;
      hls on;
      hls_path /tmp/hls;
      hls_fragment 10s;
      hls_playlist_length 120m;
      hls_nested on;
      hls_variant _480  RESOLUTION=854x480;
      hls_variant _1080 RESOLUTION=1920x1080;
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the below sample playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=854x480
a0b2e6c2-e491-31d1-9762-f18a84ac13a2_480/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=1920x1080
a0b2e6c2-e491-31d1-9762-f18a84ac13a2_1080/index.m3u8
```

The individual stream playlist files look like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:16.667,
0.ts
#EXTINF:16.667,
1.ts
#EXTINF:16.666,
2.ts
#EXTINF:16.667,
3.ts
...
```

I'm using the CDN build of Video.js, supplying all values via HTML attributes:

```html
<video-js id="my-video" class="video-js" controls autoplay preload="none" data-setup='{ "liveui": true }'>
  <source src="https://example.com/hls/a0b2e6c2-e491-31d1-9762-f18a84ac13a2.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl">
</video-js>

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video.js"></script>
```

So far, I've only been able to successfully watch the stream using Chrome (Mac and Windows), Edge, and Firefox.  It does not work on Safari (Mac or iOS), or Chrome for Android.

However, if I strip out all the transcoding and use a simple playlist, it works.  How can I get multiple streams working?